How to use Grpc-web in tauri?
I would like to use grpc-web in Tauri, but in a Tauri application, the webview can only connect to the network through its own HTTP module. Is there any way to use grpc-web in Tauri?

Searched on GitHub and Stack Overflow.
Tried running grpc-web directly in Tauri, but encountered errors.

{
    "message": "Http response at 400 or 500 level, http status code: 0",
    "stack": "Error: Http response at 400 or 500 level, http status code: 0\n    at new E (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:23:64)\n    at Y (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:59:40)\n    at rc.eval (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:57:196)\n    at Kb (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:35:182)\n    at O (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:34:614)\n    at zc (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:45:411)\n    at Bc (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:48:228)\n    at n.W (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:46:252)\n    at n.R (webpack://nico_service/./node_modules/.pnpm/grpc-web@1.5.0/node_modules/grpc-web/index.js?:46:231)",
    "code": 2,
    "metadata": {}
}


You can just send the request from the backend.
